# Copy Paste with Transpose Compilation error

Tags: excel, vba, copy, syntax-error, transpose

I know this may be a simple fix but I cant seem to de-bug it.
Can someone pleas explain why I the first past-transpose still gives me numerous errors (including syntax)

Appreciate the help.

```
Sub Clean()

Dim tRow As Long
Dim bRow As Long
Dim Range As Long

tRow = 8
bRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).row

Worksheets("Canadian").Activate

        Worksheets("Canadian").Range("E251:E267").Copy

    Worksheets("SectorSort").Activate
    .Range(.Cells((bRow + 4), "C")), (.Cells((bRow + 4), "R")).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues), Transpose:=True

 End With

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SectorSort")


    Range = bRow - tRow + 1

    .Range(.Cells(tRow, "C"), .Cells(bRow, "C")).Copy
    .Range(.Cells(bRow + 3, "C"), .Cells((bRow + 3 + Range), "C")).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt you have some ranges that are not tied to a parent

> `bRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).row`

Put this inside the with.

Then you are activating sheets, don't do that just refer to them.

Next you are treating one of those `.Activate` as a `With`

Lastly you have the `()` wrong on your paste.

---

```
Dim tRow As Long
Dim bRow As Long
Dim rng As Long

tRow = 8
Worksheets("Canadian").Range("E251:E267").Copy

With Worksheets("SectorSort")
    bRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range(.Cells((bRow + 4), "C"), .Cells((bRow + 4), "R")).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues), Transpose:=True
    rng = bRow - tRow + 1
    .Range(.Cells(tRow, "C"), .Cells(bRow, "C")).Copy
    .Range(.Cells(bRow + 3, "C"), .Cells((bRow + 3 + rng), "C")).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
End With
```